# Extending Genericons in WordPress

Tags: icon

With wordpress 4+, is it possible to create our own genericons and add them to the existing list that is bundled with WordPress? I know exactly what I want, which I can design in illustrator, but the default icons with the CMS  don't come close to it.  If so, is there a tutorial online?

I'd rather go this route than adding on an addition large font system along with  genericons.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like [Fontastic](http://fontastic.me/) or [Grunticon](http://www.grunticon.com/) to create your custom fonts/icons.

Then just add your fonts to your html with [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) or add the [head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) elements directly.

There is a section on the [Genericons GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/Genericons) that describes [Building your own Genericons](https://github.com/Automattic/Genericons#building-your-own-genericons) using [FontCustom](https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom) or [Fontello](http://fontello.com).